# How do you use the alternate color?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gimp

How do you toggle, switch, or use the alternate color in Gimp without jumping over to the toolbox and clicking the little toggle arrows? Is there a keyboard shortcut? I expected there to be a keyboard-mouse combo that would use the alternate color.

[image]

- Left mouse draws the primary color.
- Left mouse + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> uses the color picker.
- Left mouse + <kbd>Shift</kbd> draws a straight line with the primary color.
- Left mouse + <kbd>Alt</kbd> drags the window (I'm running Linux).
- Right mouse opens the context menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut to swap the foreground and background colours is `x`.

You can also adjust the shortcuts in Preferences -> Interface -> Configure Keyboard Shortcuts.

The one for swapping foreground and background is called "Swap Colors".

You can see all/most of the default Gimp keyboard shortcuts here: http://www.gimpusers.com/gimp/hotkeys